# React - onClick() event don't show clicked item's information in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data that render all items in the list. And there is a nav button works onClick and shows 2 option (edit, remove). And the problem is when I click an item nav button it shows all of the items' options. It has to trigger only one item's onClick function

```
const [drawerIsOpen, setDrawerIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const closeDrawer = () => {
        setDrawerIsOpen(false)
    }

    const openDrawer = () => {
        setDrawerIsOpen(true);
    }
```

*Below is rendered items*

```
bikes.map(bike => {
        <div className="bike-item">
               <small> {bike.title} </small>
        </div>
        <div onClick={()=> openDrawer(bike.id)} className="bike-item__actions_nav">
               <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        </div>
        <div className={`bike-item__children_actions ${drawerIsOpen && 'visible'}`}>
               <Link to={`/update/${bike.id}`} className="bike-item_actions_icon">
                  Edit
               </Link>
              <Link className="bike-item_actions_icon">
                  Remove
              </Link>
              {drawerIsOpen && <Backdrop transparent onClick={closeDrawer} />}
        </div>
```

I know there is a problem with the item's index but practically couldn't solve it.

Here is example: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-fast-swf1o?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the bikes when you call the `openDrawer` function.

Say you have state `filteredBikes` which initially will be equal to all of your bikes.

Then when you pass the id of the chosen bike into the `openDrawer` you need to update this state based on the current state of `filteredBikes`, choosing the bike whose id equals to the passed.

Comment: I couldn't make it. I created an example here is link my exact problem, check it here pls. https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-fast-swf1o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Got it, you don't want to filter, you just want to show actions on the active bike, right?
If that's the case, I would advise you to change the state from `boolean` to `string | null` with initial state of `null` and then pass id to the `openDrawer` like `onClick={() => openDrawer(bike.id)}` then in the function you can set the active id.

Then you can change `drawerIsOpen && "visible"` to `drawerIsOpen === bike.id` or something like that. Lastly, you need to reset the state when you want to close the actions menu, by calling `closeDrawer` and setting the state to the `null`.